# How to use Zend framework in window server

Tags: zend-framework

How can I use Zend Framework in window server ? I know that on window server the .htaccess file isn't supported so I have created a web.config file but this still not working.This is my  web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="index-bootstrap">
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <match url=".?" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: What is the problem to remove?

Answer (score 0):

Read articles. They should help you with the problem:

https://davekz.com/install-the-zend-framework-on-iis7-5/

http://blog.richardknop.com/2011/09/making-zend-framework-run-under-iis/

Comment: I am trying to transfer zend framework from linux to window and when trying  to login I got message in console "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error, Also I am using live server not localhost

Comment: You couldn't read both articles in 4 minutes... it's not this type of forum.

Comment: Had installed PHP? What is IIS configuration? What is ZF varsion? Lack of information to help you...

Comment: Yeah PHP is installed and ZF version is 1.1.2 and about IIS configuration I am new on window So Can to tell me how can I check IIS Configuration.

Comment: Repair your question. Put there information that I mentioned above. Give more tags like IIS, version of ZF...